# vue-cli-service test:unit trigger an "Unexpected token" on `...` (spread operator)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, testing, vue-cli

on my code i'm using `...` *(destructure operator)*. but i got "Unexpected token" on module build phase, i don't know how to fix this issue ? *(beside rewrite my code in a way without using `...` operator)*

i use `vue-cli-service test:unit src/**/*.spec.js` to run tests,

package.json:

```json
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.9",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        ...
    },
    ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem i've needed to install `@babel/preset-env` and set it on `babel.config.js` (in my case) or `.babelrc`

```js
presets: [
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
            targets: {
                esmodules: true,
            },
        }
    ]
],
```

source of solution is [this github comment](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9849#issuecomment-592668815)

also [`targets.esmodules in depth`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targetsesmodules)